# gpu ray sensor fails to scan vertically

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi
I recently encountered a problem with the gpu ray sensor. when I create a sensor that has only horizontal scans, the ray detects the object in front of it, but when I add vertical scans it does not.
When I change my sensor type from "gpu_ray" to "ray" the sensor works as expected (detects the object).

I'm currently working on gazebo 1.9.6, with Ubuntu 12.04.

I attached my XML.[simple_test.world](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/14242521428237206.world)

What am I doing wrong?

thank you.

UPDATE: I also tried this on gazebo 2.2.3 with Ubuntu 14, and got the same result.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8034/gpu-ray-sensor-fails-to-scan-vertically/) by [yotamd](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1113/yotamd/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There is an [existing issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/946/gpu-ray-sensor-vertical-ranges) on bitbucket. Please vote for it if it is of interest to you. Also, note that there is an experimental branch with partial support listed in that issue.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2015-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yotamd](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1113/yotamd/) on 2015-02-20**:
Great, thanks!